# Is it possible to run chrome in mobile emulation mode with Selenium Server with InternJS

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, testing, mobile, intern

I am trying to run Intern JS functional test-cases using local Selenium server.
I am trying to run the test cases with chrome in mobile emulated mode. But, I am not able to figure out the right configuration.

I have tried using this environment.

`environments: [
        { browserName: 'chrome'} , 
        'mobileEmulation': { "deviceName": "Google Nexus 5",
                             "deviceMetrics": {'width': 360, 
                                               'height': 640, 
                                               'pixelRatio': 3}} }
    ],`

Also, I have tried 
`capabilities: {
        'selenium-version': '2.53.1',
        'idle-timeout': 30,
        "screen-resolution": "360x640"
    }`

and

`capabilities: {
        'selenium-version': '2.53.1',
        'idle-timeout': 30,
        'mobileEmulationEnabled': true
    }`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the mobile settings defined in `capabilities.chromeOptions.mobileEmulation` :

```json
environments: [
  { browserName: 'chrome'},
],

capabilities: {
  chromeOptions: {
    mobileEmulation: { 
      deviceName: "Google Nexus 5",
      deviceMetrics: {
          width: 360, 
          height: 640, 
          pixelRatio: 3
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: It works! But, I need to use either deviceName or deviceMetrics independently.
`from unknown error: 'deviceName' must be used alone`